# Table that lists all local storage items used on site

Tags: cookie, gdpr, eu-cookie-law, storage

According to the newest regulations and our law department each website our company owns/manages needs to have a page that lists all cookies and local storage items used on the site. I tried to find some examples on how the actual list should look like. I managed to find a table of cookies that contains all cookies used on site - it has 4 columns in total: cookie name, cookie type, its purpose and duration.

Now I would like to know how a table of local storage items should look like. What information should be contained here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data provided in most modern browser Dev Tools should suffice. Below are the various sections in the Developer Tools windows where you can find the information, and a sample screenshot for each (the developer tool tabs are hyperlinked to the respective developer tool documentation for that section/feature.  Chrome gives the most details and information.

In Google Chrome, local storage and cookies can be found under the ["Application" panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#application).
[image: Chrome developer tools application tab]

In Microsoft Edge, these can be found under the ["Debugger tab"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/debugger)
[image]

In Firefox, this can be found under the ["Storage tab"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector).
[image: firefox developer tools storage tab]

Comment: I know how to find items stored in local storage. My question was "what information should be also included in the list" - In chrome dev tools there is only name in the first column and value in the second ... Our policy requires to have a single page with all these items listed on it

Comment: For the local storage, i'd recommend repurposing the table that chrome's dev tools shows- actual key for each local storage component, and a description of what the value represents, and perhaps when it is updated or cleared.